# NodeJs Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided - Not using res.render

Tags: node.js, api, post, nodes

```
    /* Add User */
router.post('/addUser', function(req, res, next) {
var matrikel_number = req.body.matrikel_number;
// var first_name = req.body.first_name;

var username = req.body.username;
var password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
var sql = `INSERT INTO users (matrikel_number, first_name, last_name, dob, email, address, phone_number, postal_code, role_id, username, password)
SELECT matrikel_number, first_name, last_name, dob, email, address, phone_number, postal_code, '1', ${username}, ${password}
FROM student_archives 
WHERE matrikel_number = ${matrikel_number}`
db.query(sql, function(err, row, fields) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({error: 'Something went wrong!'})
    }
        res.status(200).send('Success');
    })
});
```

SQL is working fine and suddenly started to get this engine error. I don't know why need help.

Comment: Can you specify more about the files? this one is you man file or just a route file? The views files are in `*.ejs` ? what packages are you using? if you are using `express` and you are using `ejs` you should set if yes in your main file(app.js or index.js or whatelse) you should specify `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` ( where `app` is equal to `require('express')()`

Comment: @Mat.C this is my route file and all the things which you mentioned are already declared in my code. It is just the problem with these line of code.

Comment: try to pass an arrow function instead a normal function inside db.query (... ), change from `db.query( sql, function (err, row, fields) {... })` to `db.query( sql, (err, row, fields) => {... })`

Comment: Formatting correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        /* Add User */
       router.post('/addUser', function(req, res, next) {
var matrikel_number = req.body.matrikel_number;
var role_id = 1
var username = req.body.username;
var password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
var sql = `INSERT INTO users (matrikel_number, first_name, last_name, dob, email, address, phone_number, postal_code, role_id, username, password) 
SELECT matrikel_number, first_name, last_name, dob, email, address, phone_number, postal_code, '${role_id}', '${username}', '${password}' 
FROM student_archives 
WHERE matrikel_number = ${matrikel_number}`
db.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        res.status(200).send('Success');
        return false;
    }
    res.status(500).send({error: 'Something went wrong, please try again!'});
})
});
```

I made the above changes and it worked. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this if u have this line in your code.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

In order to render views, there has to be some engine...
like `app.set('view engine', 'pug');`
that u haven't specified.